# Custom Key for Sort Function Doesn't Work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an array A[] of integers, A has to be sorted according to frequency of elements. If frequencies of two elements are same, then smaller number comes first.

I've tried to solve the problem using the following code using the sort function but my custom key for the sort() does not seem to work. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

```py
'''a is the input array and n is it's sizeQ'''
def sortByFreq(a,n):
    def count(k):
        return n-a.count(k)
    a.sort(key=int)
    a.sort(key=count)
    a=list(map(str,a))
    answer=' '.join(a)
    print(answer)
```

For an input array [9,9,9,2,5], the code is supposed to print 9 9 9 2 5, (as the array already is), but it prints 2 5 9 9 9 instead. (The second time I call sort it does not seem to work)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you just cannot use the original list inside a `sort` key, because `sort` uses an out of place location to compute the sort.

At some point, the original `a` is empty. Don't expect something like "all elements of `a` are in it" when calling the sort key.

In fact, if you print `a` in the `count` method, you'll get an empty list, everytime.

The workaround is to make a copy of the list and use it in the sort key (aside: no need to pass the size of the list, since `len` can compute that)

```
def sortByFreq(a):
    def count(k):
        return len(a_copy)-a_copy.count(k)

    a_copy = a.copy()  # create a copy of the list
    a.sort(key=count)
    a=list(map(str,a))
    answer=' '.join(a)
    print(answer)
```

an alternative is to pre-count elements with a counter (uses hashes, so faster). Note that you have to store the length of `a` too.

```
def sortByFreq(a):
    def count(k):
        return n-c[k]
    c = collections.Counter(a)
    n = len(a)
    a.sort(key=count)
```

finally, a shorter way would use `reverse=True` to simplify sort key, which we can turn to a `lambda`:

```
def sortByFreq(a):
    c = collections.Counter(a)
    a.sort(key=lambda k:c[k],reverse=True)
```

Comment: You could even pre-compute the counts with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) instead of copying the list

Comment: yes, that would work for hashable elements like integers, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_by_frequency(sequence):
    """Sort sequence by frequency."""
    return ''.join(sorted([char for char in sequence], key=sequence.count, reverse=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sort_by_frequency('92959'))
```